# Chat is redirecting to Area 51. WTF?

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I try to access chat I get a redirection to Area 51:

```
$ curl chat.stackoverflow.com/
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://area51.stackexchange.com/">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Was just going to ask. Check [redirect detective](http://redirectdetective.com/) - 302 redirect to area51. No clue what is going on

Comment: It is up again, just got it to reload. Still have no clue what happened in the short period ther ethough

Comment: Answered here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299891/278694

Comment: Seems to be back to normal now! Some kind of alien conspiracy, methinks.

Comment: @wim It didn't redirect to Area51 for no reason, there is definitely aliens involved :P

Comment: For context, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370331/planned-network-maintenance-scheduled-for-wednesday-september-29-0100-0400-ut#370331

Answer (score 20):

I broke it. I just unbroke it. SORRY!

Comment: Somehow or another I *know* it is Nick's fault.